# How to make the second procedure to wait untill the first procedure gets completed Using DBMS_SCHEDULER?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I need to run multiple procedures one by one. The second procedure is depends upon first one and third depends on 2nd...like that i have multiple procedures.
This is my Code. First one(A_BLOCK) is executing at the given time.

```
    BEGIN
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name             => 'mxpdm.my_job1',
       job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
       job_action           => 'BEGIN A_BLOCK; END;',
       start_date           => '04-FEB-15 2.25.00PM ASIA/CALCUTTA',
       enabled              =>  TRUE,
       comments             => 'Check');
    END;
    /
```

I don't know how to schedule and execute the second procedure B_BLOCK,after the A_BLOCK gets completed. I have searched in docs and i'm not clear,since i just started using this DBMS_SCHEDULER. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3593151/Oracle-10g-Scheduler-Enhancements-Part-2-Job-Chains.htm

Comment: I am pretty sure there are dependancies in there someplace.